# Yet another Bill-Of-Materials inquery

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store a bill-of-materials design within my database. So far, the best answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651424/bill-of-materials-database-model). Basically, have a BOM table representing a many-to-many relationship between parts and parts. Having the n-n relationship in a separate table allows you to add extra information to each "ingredient", such as a quantity.

My problem is that the given solution only accounts for making 1 of the parent object. I can combine 7 foos and 5 bars to make a widget. Unfortunately, my "recipe" for widgets can't be broken down to a single instance. My recipe says "It takes 7 foos and 5 bars, but you'll end up with 3 widgets." Given the solution in the answer linked, I would have to have partial quantities... 3/5 bar per widget. Due to business constraints, all of my ingredients must be in whole integer values.

Any advice?

Comment: you can keep the whole numbers with units of measure e.g 1 box of thingies = 10 thingies. So multiply 1 box by 10 change the UOM and end up with 4 thingies left if you make three oojahs.

Comment: It took me a minute, but I figured out what you were trying to explain. I currently have a "contracts" table for ordering parts from a wholesaler; that table includes a "package size" column. It could be that stuff we make ourselves come from a "contract" that's actually a "recipe" which links to a parts list. I'll just need to differentiate between vendor contracts and "recipe" contracts.

Comment: In inventory systems I've worked on we did have UOMs keyed by vendor. We always received in 1s though. So we ordered 1 box of 25 and when (or if :( ) it arrived we did a receipt for 25. Anything dependent on Inventory, such as creating a BOM didn't care how Acme Corp packaged them. Similarly when doing NRP we worked out how many we needed, and then ordered the "best" quantity that meant we achieved the required level without letting our engineers have too many "just in case" spares.