# Creating a Recipe Database

Tags: sql, database-schema

I am in the process of structuring a SQL database for a recipe website that I am playing around with. I am new to the many-to-many style and am not confident in what I have so far. Inevitably, what I would like the end result to do is to have a solid set up where users can:

1. Add a recipe to the database
2. Sort by prep-time, cook-time, cuisine, category, food category and course
3. Ability to generate a shopping list from a weekly meal plan by adding the total amount of ingredients from the recipes selected. (This is
       the most important!)

I will challenge myself to work out how to add the ingredients from the recipes to generate a shopping list, but the question for this post is "How should I structure my tables and connect everything?"

This is what I have so far in my SQL database:

If you think you have the answer please structure your tables similar to mine. I am a visual learner and it would be much appreciated. Also, if you could explain what I may or may not be missing would be greatly appreciated.

```
- Recipe(table)
 - recipe_id (primary key)
 - recipe_name
 - recipe_description
 - course
 - food_category
 - cuisine
 - prep_time
 - cook_time

- Ingredients(table)
 - ingredient_id (primary key)
 - ingredient_name
 - recipe_id (foreign key)

- Quantity(table)
 - quantity_id (primary key)
 - recipe_id (foreign key)
 - ingredient_id (foreign key)
 - ingredient_quantity
 - ingredient_measurement

- Recipe Steps(table)
 - step_id (primary key)
 - step_description
 - recipe_id (foreign key)

- Join(table)*
 - join_id (primary key)
 - recipes_id(foreign key)
 - ingredients_id(foreign key)
 - quantity
```

// I do not know if I need this 'join' table since 'quantity' seems to be similar

Thank you in advance!

Comment: no it does not because this about table structure and not about, you know, getting code reviewed

Comment: Does it work as intended? What's your exact question?

Comment: @Amy Please read what is on topic for Code Review before you pre-maturely recommend migration.

Comment: The OP is soliciting for opinions.  It isn't a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Amy That doesn't make it automagically on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @Amy It should either be cleaned up, or not be on the SE network at all.

Comment: DBA might take it, not sure.

Comment: Just because it is off-topic on SO doesn't mean it is on topic anywhere on the SE network. I can't recommend to the DBA SE as I don't post there, so maybe someone who is more knowledgeable can, but some questions *can be off-topic for SE completely*, and that's completely fine.

Comment: Note that join_id is redundant. You have a perfectly serviceable natural primary key, without the need for a surrogate. It's fine to have a quantity (or units) table, but this wouldn't likely store information about ingredients. So, you're right. You're doubling up on yourself, but that's normal when starting out. You're basically heading in the right direction.

Comment: I would think recipe + ingredients/shopping list could be modeled as a [Bill of Materials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651424/bill-of-materials-database-model)  No endorsement of this Q&A, just providing something to search against

Comment: @Mast, My exact question is "How to step up the structure of the tables and how to connect them for a recipe database". Would what I have currently be an acceptable setup, could there be any problems with it, could there be any improvements that you might see?

Comment: @Strawberry, I thought I might need to remove the join table, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @billinkc, Thanks for sharing. I am currently looking into it. How did you create that image structure of your table set up?

Comment: @Amy, I am looking for help on the subject so any constructive criticism is helpful

Answer (score 16):

As I'm not 100% sure what you want. I assume you're asking what might be the best database and table structure for your project. As I'm not completely sure what the scope of the project entails, I can only provide the following based on assumptions of field names and assumptions of project structure.

### Database and table structure

**Recipe(table)**

- recipe_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- course_id **int** *foreign_key*
- food_category_id **int** *foreign_key*
- recipe_name **varchar**
- recipe_description **varchar**
- cuisine **not sure**
- prep_time **time**
- cook_time **time**

  **Food Category(table)**
- food_category_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- food_category_name **varchar**

  **Course(table)**
- course_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- course_name **varchar**
- *other course properties maybe, such as time of day?*

  **Ingredients(table)**
- ingredient_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- ingredient_name **varchar**
- *other ingredient properties maybe?*

  **Quantity(table)**
- quantity_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- recipe_id **int** *foreign_key*
- ingredient_id **int** *foreign_key*
- ingredient_measurement_id **int** *foreign_key*
- ingredient_quantity **float**

  **Measurements(table)**
- measurement_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- measurement_name **varchar**

  **Recipe Steps(table)**
- step_id **int** *primary_key* *auto_increment*
- recipe_id **int** *foreign_id*
- step_number **int**
- step_description **varchar**

The Join table is useless as you'd be joining the tables in your `SELECT` query
i.e. the following queries

---

### Example queries

**Getting recipe details - Recipe query**
Assuming a search parameter has been entered - i.e. *chocolate*

```
SELECT
        r.recipe_id AS recipeID,
        r.recipe_name AS recipeName,
        r.recipe_description AS recipeDescription,
        r.cuisine AS cuisine,
        r.prep_time AS prepTime,
        r.cook_time AS cookTime,
        c.course_name AS course,
        f.food_category_name AS foodCategory
    FROM Recipe AS r
    JOIN course AS c ON c.course_id = r.course_id
    JOIN food_category AS fc ON fc.food_category_id = r.food_category_id
    WHERE r.recipe_name LIKE '%chocolate%'
        AND c.course_id = 1 -- i.e. breakfast as course_name
    ORDER BY r.prep_time -- for example
```

Assuming the user has selected a recipe (with ID = `123`) in the list of recipes that showed up with "chocolate" in the name

**Listing ingredients (using recipeID from user-selected recipe)**

```
SELECT
        i.ingredient_name AS ingredientName,
        q.ingredient_quantity AS ingredientQuantity,
        m.measurement_name AS measurementName
    FROM ingredients AS i
    JOIN quantity AS q ON q.ingredient_id = i.ingredient_id
    JOIN measurements AS m ON m.measurement_id = q.ingredient_measurement_id
    JOIN recipe AS r ON r.recipe_id = q.recipe_id
    WHERE r.recipe_id = 123
    ORDER BY i.ingredient_name ASC
```

**Listing steps (using recipeID from user-selected recipe)**

```
SELECT
        s.step_number AS stepNo,
        s.step_description AS stepDescription
    FROM steps AS s
    JOIN recipe AS r ON r.recipe_id = s.recipe_id
    WHERE r.recipe_id = 123
    ORDER BY s.step_number ASC
```

---

P.S. the more control you have over the content in the database (i.e. the course names - your initial structure does not involve any control over this content) the better and easier it will be for you in the end. For example: If a user creates a recipe with the course "Breakfast" and another creates a recipe with the course "Brekfast" and you try to organize your recipes by course "breakfast" you're going to run into some fun issues and you're going to have to either forget about that method of organization or manipulate your database to accommodate for something that should have been done initially